# OpenSearch javascript methods

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser, opera, opensearch

It seems only Chrome supports `IsSearchProviderInstalled` method. IE8+ and Firefox always return 0.

Is there any reason for deprecating `IsSearchProviderInstalled` method in IE8+?

Is there any alternative? I want to remove add button if my search provider is already installed.

Also is there any alternative for this IE/Firefox method in Opera Browser?

```
window.external.AddSearchProvider('opensearch.xml')
```

Opera has its own way to add search provider. Is there any way to add a search provider to it using JS?

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa342526(v=vs.85).aspx

Also see:https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=340604